# Form data are not sorted in database

Tags: php, cakephp

I am developing the one register form in cakephp mvc architecture,but when i submit the form data is not stored in database.

database:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
username VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL ,
password VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL ,
email VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
first_name VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL ,
last_name VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL
)
```

model class:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel
{
var $name='User';
}
?>
```

view class:

```
<html>
<form action="../users/register" method="post">
<p>Please fill out the form below to register an account.</p>
<label>Username:</label><input name="username" size="40" />
<label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" size="40"
/>
<label>Email Address:</label><input name="email" size="40"
maxlength="255" />
<label>First Name:</label><input name="first_name" size="40" />
<label>Last Name:</label><input name="last_name" size="40" />
<input type="submit" value="register" />
</form>
</html>
```

controller class:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController
{
function register(){
if (!empty($this->params['form']))
{
if($this->User->save($this->params['form']))
{
$this->flash('Registration Successful','/users/register');
}
else
{
$this->flash('Not succeeded','/users/register');
}
}
}
}
?>
```

please solve the problem.

Comment: which version of cakephp do you use?

Comment: i am using cakephp 2.4 version

Comment: Oke, and did you read the documentation? Because you can use cakephp code to add data to the database... http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: yes i already read the documentaion upto mvc architecture.if i run the above code blank screen will be seen in my browser

Comment: blank screen? do you have debug modus on `(2)` ?

Comment: i am new to cakephp.how to debug mode on

Comment: in you `app/config/core.php` you will find a line like `Configure::write('debug', 2);` check it is set to `2` and not `0`

Comment: It set as Configure::write('debug', 2);

Comment: Still blank page? My advise if you are new to cakephp, follow the tutorial in the documentation...

Comment: i read the documentation and now i am practicing the examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for cake 2.X

View file

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
        'controller' => 'users', 'action'=>'register'
    ));

    echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
        'size'=>40,
        'type' => 'text',
        'placeholder'=>__('Your username'),
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
        'size'=>40,
        'type' => 'password',
        'placeholder'=>__('password'),
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
        'size'=>40,
        'type' => 'email',
        'placeholder'=>__('your@email.com'),
    ));

    echo $this->Form->input('first_name', array(
        'size'=>40,
        'type' => 'text',
        'placeholder'=>__('First name'),
    ));

    echo $this->Form->input('last_name', array(
        'size'=>40,
        'type' => 'text',
        'placeholder'=>__('Last name'),
    ));
    echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

Controller

```
public function register(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        if($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Registered'));
            $this->redirect('/');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Something went wrong!'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows the error message like missing The action index is not defined in controller UsersController

Comment: If i mention that index() in controller,blank screen will be displayed in my browser.

Comment: change path here $this->redirect('/'); or remove that line if you don't want redirect

Comment: it shows the error msg   Using $this when not in object context
File: D:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\Model\User.php
Line: 9

Comment: you have **public function register()** or **function register()** First one is correct

Answer (score 0):

try

$this->User->save($this->params['data']);

or

$this->User->save($this->request->data);